# How to convert RISC-V Executable from rv64gc to rv32im

Tags: gcc, compilation, llvm, cpu-architecture, riscv

Executable codes can be converted to the assembly by using objdump. We can convert this objdump for another target by hand (by writing different assembly codes when needed lines, of course with the address correction at the end). However, I wonder if there is an automatic conversion from one executable to another target executable.

Comment: You can decompile *most* of such assembly into C, and then compile back into a different architecture. But don't expect the result to be efficient and 100% semantically equivalent.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. It does not matter. It already should behave differently because the architecture will be different (Of course, it should make calculations true although in a different way). I google it. I couldn't find a way rather than ghidra. Did you refer to such a method or there is a standard way to convert elf to c code?

Comment: There's no standard decompiler, but it's relatively easy to write one, especially if you don't care much about performance.

Comment: I searched a bit but couldn't find an easy way to write a decompiler. But I will try to deal with it different ways. Thank you for helping me.

Comment: Well, I said *relatively* easy... In a way, `qemu` is doing a good chunk of decompilation before re-compiling the code dynamically. To decompile machine code you need to disassemble it, then find basic blocks, then convert all the registers to abstract variables, then convert to SSA, and after that it's trivial to reconstruct a relatively efficient C representation.

Comment: Thank you so much. I will look for Ghidra and Qemu for this purpose.